# Brackets p5.js won't load Sound: Error "The request status was: 0 ()"

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js, adobe-brackets

My sound files won't load when I use the Live Preview within Brackets, the screen only shows "Loading..." and within the Console it states:

> The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.
> Unable to load assets/jump.wav. The request status was: 0 ()

This is my code:

```
var jumpSound;

function preload()
{
    soundFormats('mp3','wav');
//    
    //load your sounds here
    jumpSound = loadSound('assets/jump.wav');
    jumpSound.setVolume(0.1);


}


function setup()
{
    createCanvas(1024, 576);
    floorPos_y = height * 3/4;
    lives = 3;
    
    startGame();
    jumpSound.play();
```

I tried changing my mp3's to wav and it worked for a bit but when I opened it up again later on it went back to the same error, so I know it's written correctly but it seems to be a technical issue with brackets or p5.js? Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Wav is a bad idea for web audio, as wav files are huge compared to mp3 or ogg counterparts (I personally prefer ogg, as mp3 usually leaves a gap of silence in the beginning).

Leaving that aside, some more context would be nice, like when you call the function. I can recommend you to make a local server to host your program, that helped me with some problems loading files in the past.
An easy way to do this is using a chrome extension called 'Web server for chrome', in which you just select the folder where the index.html file is, and then it gives you a link you can open to run the file.

Comment: The reason I used wav is because I originally used mp3 files and it was giving me issues so I converted them to see if it would work. But I'll try using a local server, sorry I'm very new so I'm not sure how but I'll look up the web server for chrome as you mentioned.  I'll edit my original post to show how my code looks thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to update us on whatever is giving you trouble, and we will do our best to help!